# How to Show or Hide an HTML Element in the DOM Based on its Index Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a quiz in which their are six questions (no right or wrong answers).

The questions are hidden in the HTML except for the first. There is a "Next" button at the bottom of the quiz. When people click "Next" after answering each question, I want it to find the question that is visible, hide it and then show the next question.

I'm having trouble doing this. I know that I can hide all of the elements or show all of the elements, but I want to show only the next question that is hidden. For instance, on page load, question 1 is visible. When the user clicks next, question 1 should be hidden and question 2 should display. The rest of the questions should remain hidden. When the next button is clicked again, question 2 will be hidden and question 3 will be visible, and so on. I can't seem to figure this out. I tried to use the jquery each function and to somehow target the questions by index, but it didn't work.

Here is my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amykirst/st5639ud/

HTML:

```
<section class="questions">
<h2 class="outline">Question</h2>

<p class="questionNumber">Question 1 of 5</p>

<div class="question">
  <p class="questionText">What is your age range?</p>

  <form>
    <select class="demo">
      <option value="20-34">
        20-34
      </option>

      <option value="35-39">
        35-39
      </option>

      <option value="40-44">
        40-44
      </option>

      <option value="45-49">
        45-49
      </option>

      <option value="50-54">
        50-54
      </option>

      <option value="55-59">
        55-59
      </option>

      <option value="60-64">
        60-64
      </option>

      <option value="65-69">
        65-69
      </option>

      <option value="70-74">
        70-74
      </option>

      <option value="75-79">
        75-79
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div><!--end questionAge -->

<div class="question hide">
  <p class="questionText">What is your total cholesterol?</p>

  <form>
    <select>
      <option value="Less than 160">
        Less than 160
      </option>

      <option value="160-199">
        160-199
      </option>

      <option value="200-239">
        200-239
      </option>

      <option value="240-279">
        240-279
      </option>

      <option value="Greater than 279">
        Greater than 279
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <div class="tip">
    <p>Don't know your total cholesterol? Attend one of our free
    screenings. <a href="http://www.chsbuffalo.org/events" target=
    "_blank">Click here to view upcoming screenings in our events
    calendar.</a></p>
  </div>
</div><!-- end cholesterol -->

<div class="question hide">
  <p class="questionText">Are you a smoker?</p>

  <form>
      <input name="smoker" type="radio" value="Yes"/>Yes<br/>
      <input name="smoker" type="radio" value="No"/>No<br/>
  </form>
</div><!-- end questionSmoker -->

<div class="question hide">
  <p class="questionText">What is your high-density lipoprotein (HDL)
  cholesterol level?</p>

  <form>
    <select>
      <option value="60">
        60
      </option>

      <option value="50-59">
        50-59
      </option>

      <option value="40-49">
        40-49
      </option>

      <option value="Less than 40">
        Less than 40
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <div class="tip">
    <p>HDL cholesterol is also known as “good” cholesterol. If you
    don’t know your HDL level, ask your doctor for a cholesterol
    test.</p>

    <p>Don’t have a doctor? <a href=
    "http://www.chsbuffalo.org/physicians">Click here to find a primary
    care doctor near you.</a></p>
  </div>
</div><!-- end questionHDL -->

<div class="question hide">
  <p class="questionText">Are you on blood pressure medication?</p>

  <form>
      <input name="medication" type="radio" value="Yes"/>Yes<br/>
      <input name="medication" type="radio" value="No"/>No<br/>
  </form>
</div><!-- end questionMed -->

<div class="question hide">
  <p class="questionText">What is your Systolic Blood Pressure reading
  (first number)?</p>

  <form>
    <select>
      <option value="Less than 120">
        Less than 120
      </option>

      <option value="120-129">
        120-129
      </option>

      <option value="130-139">
        130-139
      </option>

      <option value="140-159">
        140-159
      </option>

      <option value="Greater than 159">
        Greater than 159
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <div class="tip">
    <p>Don't know your blood pressure? Attend one of our free
    screenings. <a href="http://www.chsbuffalo.org/events" target=
    "_blank">Click here to view upcoming screenings in our events
    calendar.</a></p>
  </div>
</div><!-- end questionSBP -->

<div>
    <form name="next">
        <input type="button" class="next" value="Next"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
display:none;
```

}

Comment: it seems like you are not super clear on what each part of your jquery is doing. try making a simpler html example and play around with the jquery there. (remember: you are trying to learn how to code, not just to get the "right" answer).

Comment: alternative approach: this data is coming from somewhere, so put it in your JS, and generate the DOM off of that, instead of hardcoding it in your HTML. Then you also have direct references to things that "next" needs to toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var pos = 0;
$(".next").click(function () {
    pos++
    $(".question").hide();
    $(".question").eq(pos).show();

});
```

You'll need your question header "Question 1 of 5" inside your question wrapper as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to refer to the questions by index number but I didn't know how to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your loop, that makes it do it a lot of times, all you need to do it's get the reference to the question that it's visible and hide it and then use the next() to get the reference to the next question.

http://jsfiddle.net/st5639ud/10/

```
$(".next").click(function () {       
    $(".question:visible").hide().next(".question").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Or instead of using hide() you can add the 'hide' class

http://jsfiddle.net/st5639ud/12/

```
$(".question:visible").addClass('hide').next(".question").removeClass("hide");
```